# Wordpress - WooCommerce - Typo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Bit of an issue I'm having with the WooCommerce plugin on WP.

When installed, it points to a default store page (changeable to other pages). However, whichever page it points to is completely blank in the WP editor, but has assets like a sidebar and product menu when previewed/published.

This is somewhat editable within WooCommerce's customise tab in WP. You can add/remove sidebar.

[screenshot of the customise tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0jX5.png)

However, I cannot for the life of me remove the product menu from the page because the editor shows a blank page, but WC is adding in its default assets. Its default assets would be fine, if it wasn't for the typo in the sidebar. 'Brows by categories' instead of 'Browse by categories' is utterly infuriating.

[screenshot of the published page with iffy sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAGRX.png)

I could remove the store page entirely, but I want to run it in catalog mode which removes 'add to cart' and everything that goes with it.

The aim of the page is to essentially show products available in store, with all the details like a store page, but without the purchasing functionality.

So far I've tried:
Uninstalling and reinstalling plugin
Editing HTML on the page (nothing shows just like the edit page)
Removing default store page (this disables catalog mode, the plugin I need)

I wouldn't be against ditching WooCommerce if I was able to setup a product catalog by other means. WooCommerce' system would be so good if it weren't for that ruddy typo!!

Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is fullly customizable, it has a lot of action/filter which you can hook into to edit things or just overwrite his template file by simply copying them into your theme main directory inside the "woocommerce" folder (if you don't have it already, simply create it).

After you created that directory you can copy any file from the /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates directory and just make it become w/e you want =)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to anything beyond the WP editor. Someone else hosts this for me.

Comment: If you have no access to any file then it is going to be a lot harder for you to fix that little issue. Maybe ask your host an FTP access?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a personalized shopping page with the elementor plugin.
Working with elementor is very simple and you can get the result you want with a simple Google search.

I hope I could help.